# Optional keyword argument being filled with non-default value unless specified

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have a function, create, which accepts these arguments:

```py
create(self, name, val={})
```

It is part of a class which has an attribute also named val, so note that `val` and `self.val` are two different objects.

Somehow, the value of `val` has been replaced with `self.val`, which is leading to some recursion issues in my module.

The module in question, named [pyndb](https://github.com/jvadair/pyndb), basically takes a dictionary and represents each key with a custom `Node` object. These objects then do the same process (if the key's value is another dictionary) for all of the keys they hold. If it helps, I've documented the whole module [here](https://pen.jvadair.com/books/pyndb).

If you take a look at the module and the specific process to reproduce this error as I detail [here](https://github.com/jvadair/pyndb/issues/1), you will notice that this only occurs when trying to create the 3rd object inwards of the main class. The value of said object should be an empty dictionary, as I did not change the default value of the `val` argument. However, if I set `val` to an empty dictionary manually, there are no issues.

The part that stumps me the most is why this only affects the 3rd `Node` inwards.

The source code for the module is in the GitHub repository which I linked above, and the module is available for install with pip:

```
pip3 install pyndb
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) Please update your question to include a self-contained [minimal, reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't accept links to external sites. 2) It looks like your issue may be due `create` using a mutable default argument. If `create` assigns `val` to `self.val` anywhere, you may end up with `val` referencing the same object as `self.val` on all subsequent calls that use the default argument. See [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: This makes sense now that I have read the accepted answer on that post. I didn't realize that keyword arguments were only defined once, and could be changed like this. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I specifically understand the question, but I suspect that your issue is coming from using a mutable object as a default variable. To give you an example imagine I have a function which goes

```
def add_to_list(item, l=[]):
    l.append(item)
    return l
```

If I then call it once I get what you expect

```
>>> add_to_list(1)
[1]
```

BUT, this has now permanently altered the value of the `l` default variable, which means that if I now type

```
>>> add_to_list(2)
[1,2]
```

I get both elements instead of one.

To fix your problem I'd suggest

```
def create(self, name, val=None):
    if not val:
        val = {}
```

As a workaround.